# Grub customizer is not opening

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, customization

1-Hello i just completely uninstalled windows from my computer.

So the problem is when i restart my computer i always see dual boot menu , i found grub customize and downloaded it but its not opening . İts just not opening .
(Ubuntu version 21.10)

(I tried downloading in terminal and tried downloading at Ubuntu software didn't worked for me )

Is there any other way to remove dual boot menu or how can i solve this problem ?

2-Also i found that when i type (SOLVED)

`sudo apt update`

at the end it says

`Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu impish Release 404  Not Found [IP: ]`

`Reading package lists... Done`

`E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.`

`N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`

`N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

Comment: Hello. I do not know why it does not open but the update error is because of the PPA. Remove that line from the sources list and update should be fine.

Comment: When I installed that app I did not use a PPA. I used instructions like these. https://ubunlog.com/en/grub-customizer-personaliza-menu-grub/

Comment: @David ahh error is gone thanks

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi before entering command do i need to install grub again because i removed it

Comment: Great and I see someone jumped in and gave you my answer.

Comment: @David its so weird that its just not opening nothing appears , there is error do you know any other grub customizer repo

Comment: No I do not know of another. Have you rebooted the machine? Have you done an update and upgrade?

Comment: @David  i got the error message you can see its down Archisman Panigrahi answer  and yes i rebooted and updated , upgraded it ( i will open new question about it )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grub customizer is available on the [official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=grub-customizer) in Ubuntu 20.04+, and the PPA does not host packages for recent versions of Ubuntu.

First, remove the PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-reposiory -r danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt update
```

Now install grub customizer from the official repositories.

```
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

You can also run `sudo update-grub` to remove the empty entries from the grub menu.

Comment: I've done everything but its not opening . There is no error and nothing appears when i click grub customizer but thanks for help

Comment: Can you run `grub-customizer` in terminal, and post the output (by editing in your question)?

Comment: `localuser:root being added to access control list` 
` Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused` 

` (grub-customizer:14287): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:32:45.674: cannot open display: 
localuser:root being removed from access control list`

Comment: Are you running a desktop computer? Also, can you ask a new question about this new issue (it works for me)? This question was about the PPA error.

Comment: Okay thanks for you helping now I have a concrete problem which i need thanks btw i use desktop computer yes